# Getting an error in npm in my ubuntu operating system

Tags: npm

I am trying to install **vite** package of **NPM** using command: `npm i vite`
and getting these errors. I have to install it to use it can anyone help to get rid of this?

> npm ERR! code EPERM npm ERR! syscall symlink npm ERR! path
> ../esbuild/bin/esbuild npm ERR! dest /media/godkk/HELLO/Apna
> College/Delta/CSS/TailWind/node_modules/.bin/esbuild npm ERR! errno -1
> npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink
> '../esbuild/bin/esbuild' -> '/media/godkk/HELLO/Apna
> College/Delta/CSS/TailWind/node_modules/.bin/esbuild' npm ERR!
> [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink
> '../esbuild/bin/esbuild' -> '/media/godkk/HELLO/Apna
> College/Delta/CSS/TailWind/node_modules/.bin/esbuild'] { npm ERR!
> errno: -1, npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM', npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
> npm ERR!   path: '../esbuild/bin/esbuild', npm ERR!   dest:
> '/media/godkk/HELLO/Apna
> College/Delta/CSS/TailWind/node_modules/.bin/esbuild' npm ERR! } npm
> ERR!  npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
> npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this
> file as the current user npm ERR!  npm ERR! If you believe this might
> be a permissions issue, please double-check the npm ERR! permissions
> of the file and its containing directories, or try running npm ERR!
> the command again as root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /home/godkk/.npm/_logs/2024-03-03T06_59_01_888Z-debug-0.log

Comment: This is a permissions error where it's not allowing you to create a symlink (like it says at the bottom).  Give more details about that directory, how it is mounted into your filesystem, and what permissions it has.

Comment: Hi, the EPERM error typically indicates a permissions problem during the `npm` package installation process. Try `sudo npm cache clean --force` then use `sudo npm i vite`. Let me know if this solved your problem